# пароль в laravel показать

Tags: laravel, laravel5

подскажите, как при выводе в профиле пользователя показать не хешированный пароль?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию - никак. В стандартной настройке пароль хранится в хэшированном виде, и вы его никак не покажете пользователю. Можете самостоятельно запрограммировать хранение plain пароля и передавать его пользователю, но это (по моему мнению) дыра в безопасности.

Обычно пароль показывают, когда его вводят, а не когда он уже сохранен.

Comment: у меня есть форма профиля, я вывожу туда инфу, чтобы потом изменить, и вот пароль выводится в хешированном виде, а хотелось пользователю показать его пароль

Comment: обычно пароли просят изменить, а не показывают. Некоторые еще заставляют ввести старый перед изменением. Но чтобы показывать текущий парол? (заодно любому злоумышленнику который посмотрел на залогиненый сайт)

Comment: *Обычно пароль показывают, когда его вводят, а не когда он уже сохранен* - сохраняют не пароль, а его хеш.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо